# Problem with simple numerical estimation for MLE of multinomial in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, mle

I am trying to set up a simple numerical MLE estimation of a multinomial distribution.

The multinomial has one constraint - all the cell probabilities need to add up to one.

Usually the way to have this constraint is to re-express one of the probabilities as (1 - sum of the others)

When I run this however, I have a problem as during the optimization procedure, I might have logarithm of a negative value.

Any thoughts of how to fix this? I tried using another optimization package (Rsolnp) and it worked, but I am trying to make it work with the simple default R optim in order to avoid constrained/nonlinear optimization.

Here is my code (I know that I can get the result in this particular case analytically, but this is a toy example, my actual problem is bigger than this here).

```
set.seed(1234)
test_data <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1000, prob = rep(1/4, 4))
N <- test_data
loglik_function <- function(theta){
  output <- -1*(N[1]*log(theta[1]) + N[2]*log(theta[2]) + N[3]*log(theta[3]) + N[4]*log(1- sum(theta)))
  return(output)
}

startval <- rep(0.1, 3)

my_optim <- optim(startval, loglik_function, lower = 0.0001, upper = 0.9999, method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Any thoughts or help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your upper limit for each theta is 0.9999. You estimate three thetas and there is nothing preventing their sum to become greater than 1.

Comment: @Roland, right, I am looking for an idea that prevents them being summed up to more than one. Each parameter in the data generating process can theoretically be in the whole interval of (0,1).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `optim`.

Comment: @ Roland, I know, right? I was thinking this too...Rsolnp does the job, I was just looking for a way to have a "plain-vanilla" package solution. I tried to set up constrOptim as well, but I did not manage to put in the equality constraint.

Comment: @Jean_N For what it's still worth, I've added a constrained ML estimation example using `maxLik` in my post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full heads-up: I know you asked about (constrained) ML estimation, but how about doing this the Bayesian way à la Stan/`rstan`. I will remove this if it's not useful/missing the point.

1. The model is only a few lines of code.

   ```
   library(rstan)

   model_code <- "
   data {
       int<lower=1> K;           // number of choices
       int<lower=0> y[K];        // observed choices
   }

   parameters {
       simplex[K] theta;         // simplex of probabilities, one for every choice
   }

   model {
       // Priors
       theta ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);   // weakly informative
       // Likelihood
       y ~ multinomial(theta);
   }

   generated quantities {
       real ratio;
       ratio = theta[1] / theta[2];
   }
   "
   ```

   You can see how easy it is to implement the simplex constraint on the `theta`s using the Stan data type `simplex`. In the Stan language, [`simplex`](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/simplex-transform-section.html) allows you to easily implement a [probability (unit) simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex)

   [image]

   where K denotes the number of parameters (here: choices).

   Also note how we use the `generated quantities` code block, to calculate derived quantities (here `ratio`) based on the parameters (here `theta[1]` and `theta[2]`). Since we have access to the posterior distributions of all parameters, calculating the distribution of derived quantities is trivial.
2. We then fit the model to your `test_data`

   ```
   fit <- stan(model_code = model_code, data = list(K = 4, y = test_data[, 1]))
   ```

   and show a summary of the parameter estimates

   ```
   summary(fit)$summary
   #                 mean      se_mean         sd          2.5%           25%
   #theta[1]     0.2379866 0.0002066858 0.01352791     0.2116417     0.2288498
   #theta[2]     0.26 20013 0.0002208638 0.01365478     0.2358731     0.2526111
   #theta[3]     0.2452539 0.0002101333 0.01344665     0.2196868     0.2361817
   #theta[4]     0.2547582 0.0002110441 0.01375618     0.2277589     0.2458899
   #ratio        0.9116350 0.0012555320 0.08050852     0.7639551     0.8545142
   #lp__     -1392.6941655 0.0261794859 1.19050097 -1395.8297494 -1393.2406198
   #                   50%           75%         97.5%    n_eff      Rhat
   #theta[1]     0.2381541     0.2472830     0.2645305 4283.904 0.9999816
   #theta[2]     0.2615782     0.2710044     0.2898404 3822.257 1.0001742
   #theta[3]     0.2448304     0.2543389     0.2722152 4094.852 1.0007501
   #theta[4]     0.2545946     0.2638733     0.2822803 4248.632 0.9994449
   #ratio        0.9078901     0.9648312     1.0764747 4111.764 0.9998184
   #lp__     -1392.3914998 -1391.8199477 -1391.3274885 2067.937 1.0013440
   ```

   as well as a plot showing point estimates and CIs for the `theta` parameters

   ```
   plot(fit, pars = "theta")
   ```

   [image]

---

### Update: Constrained ML estimation using `maxLik`

You can in fact implement constrained ML estimation using methods provided by the `maxLik` library. I found it a bit "fiddly", because convergence seems to be quite sensitive to changes in the starting values and the optimisation method used.

For what it's worth, here is a reproducible example:

```
library(maxLik)

x <- test_data[, 1]
```

Define the log-likelihood function for a multinomial distribution; I've included an `if` statement here to prevent `theta < 0` cases from throwing an error.

```
loglik <- function(theta, x)
    if (all(theta > 0)) sum(dmultinom(x, prob = theta, log = TRUE)) else 0
```

I use the Nelder-Mead optimisation method here to find the maximum of the log-likelihood function. The important bit here is the `constraints` argument that implements a constraint in the form of the equality `A theta + B = 0`, see `?maxNM` for details and examples.

```
res <- maxNM(
    loglik,
    start = rep(0.25, length(x)),
    constraints = list(
        eqA = matrix(rep(1, length(x)), ncol = length(x)),
        eqB = -1),
    x = x)
```

We can inspect the results

```
summary(res)
--------------------------------------------
Nelder-Mead maximization
Number of iterations: 111
Return code: 0
successful convergence
Function value: -10.34576
Estimates:
      estimate     gradient
[1,] 0.2380216 -0.014219040
[2,] 0.2620168  0.012664714
[3,] 0.2450181  0.002736670
[4,] 0.2550201 -0.002369234

Constrained optimization based on SUMT
Return code: 1
penalty close to zero
1  outer iterations, barrier value 5.868967e-09
--------------------------------------------
```

and confirm that indeed the sum of the estimates equals 1 (within accuracy)

```
sum(res$estimate)
#[1] 1.000077
```

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(1234)
test_data <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = 1000, prob = rep(1/4, 4))
```

Comment: On the contrary, I quite like that you have seen it from a different angle :) Incidentally, I have been also working with stan these days, just getting into it.

The question from above is a simple example of  a bigger problem that's being approached fully from a frequentist point of view at the moment, maybe one day I might look at a Bayesian approach too :)

By the way, the model (multinomial) still needs to have the constraint that the pi's sum up to one, in order for the model to be defined. I wonder how this constraint is kept within the Bayesian inference framework?

Comment: @Jean_N *"By the way, the model (multinomial) still needs to have the constraint that the pi's sum up to one, in order for the model to be defined."* In the Stan model the constraint is implemented through the `simplex` data type (see `model_code` above). No extra work required:-)

Comment: aah yes I see it indeed. And the simplex restricts you on (0,1) for each parameter so it works out beautifully. Furthermore, I guess the posterior is limited to have only positive values, so you don't run into issues with the inference for the pi-s, unlike what you might have using large sample results from the MLE estimation. Very nice, thank you for showing a different approach!

Comment: @Jean_N Yes, apologies for not making that clearer. I've made an edit to explain the `simplex` type in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you again for the edit, I will take a look at that package. Rsolnp seems to be  faster, but I'll check this one out too. Just piggybacking on your response with the Bayesian approach (you really got me curious) - how hard is it to find correct posterior of functions of those parameters? Like, e.g. if I wanted to find the correct posterior or theta[1]/theta[2], how much more work would that involve and how would the code change? My bayesian classes were long time ago, but I seem to remember that I would just have to sample from the posteriors for each theta and every time build the ratio

Comment: I am marking this as the answer - even if it is not directly related to optim, it is an extensive and informative answer.

Comment: @Jean_N *"if I wanted to find the correct posterior or theta[1]/theta[2], how much more work would that involve and how would the code change? "* It would add 4 more lines of code:-) That's what the `generated quantities` code block in Stan is for, I've modified my Stan/`rsrtan` example to demonstrate. Please take a look.

Comment: Cheers man, had it figured out as well at some point today :). Stan's impressive, I think I might actually look into approaching my whole problem from a Bayesian point of view, the problem I am working on is a bit more complex function of the counts and frequentist inference is nice but a bit tedious to work out the large sample variance for my estimator. Apart from stan's guide, do you have any idea of an easier guide to start with? Cheers and thanks again for looking at the problem from another angle! (that got me looking at it from another angle too)

Comment: @Jean_N I'm a big fan of Stan/`rstan` so far as well. We've been using it in various projects, and so far I've always been impressed about how easy it is to set up a model. I would call it a mathematically intuitive way. And that's even without using the `rstanarm` and/or `brms` packages that make things even easier for standard problems. In terms of practical guides, my two go-to books are Gelman & Hill, *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*, and Gelman et al., *Bayesian Data Analysis*.

Comment: Happy to send you some details involving those books, send me an email.